# How to save curve shape of cylinder with such deform?

Tags: modeling, topology

It's difficult for me to make clear this part of bullet.
[image]

I use cylinder with 16 vertices, add 2 horizontal loops "ctrl+r", insert "i" 2x loops. Then I extrude with individual origins and normal transform orientation polygons
[image]

Then I add subdivision surface and some loops to save form. But there are problem with entrance 5 edges in vertices and bad form of curve shape
[image]

How to save curve shape of cylinder with such deformations and to get it with clear topology?

**LukeD, thanks for solution to the problem**. Here's my result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Shrinkwrap Modifier** with **Vertex Group** and another **Cylinder** as **Guide mesh** to do this.

[image]

1. Create **Cylinder** in the same place as original. Lets call it **Guide Mesh**. It can be higher (Z axis) but it should have exactly same **Radius**. Without top/bottom faces. Add to it **Subdivision Surface** Modifier - Subdivisions 6. You can **Hide** it.

   [image: first]
2. **In Original Mesh** (the one you have modeled) select outside vertices. The ones that should be perfectly round. Add **Vertex Group** and **Assign** them.

   [image: second]
3. Add to the **Original Mesh Shrinkwrap Modifier** and choose created **Vertex Group** and **Guide Mesh** as a **Target**.

   [image: third]

> Note: You will need to Apply Shrinkwrap modifier in order to
>   move/scale/rotate mesh or you can do this with Guide Mesh selected
>   also.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid inset geometry on curved surfaces. Try something like this:

[image]