# curved indentation surface

Tags: modeling, topology

What is the most clean topology to achieve this indented surface in the tube cap?
[image]

I'm unable to move forward since the inset surface is curved not just flat.
[image]

Boolean operations would not be useful since I need a clean topology to add a subdivision surface modifier later.

Comment: Could you add your .blend file to your original question using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You can use Boolean for that and then repair geometry there. Or you can construct that indentation separately preserving the same vertex count for sides as in the resulting mesh around that place and then delete part of surface from resulting mesh and put new one there.Things like retopo in this case probably would sound too complex

Comment: @Dontwalk I believe there's no need for this in this type of questions

Comment: @MrZak I usually try to avoid booleans as much as possible since they take me too long to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** I've used method from here: [How to save curve shape of cylinder with
>   such deform?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96342/how-to-save-curve-shape-of-cylinder-with-such-deform/96344#96344) with Shrinkwrap modifier to place vertices in oval
>   shape without distorting overall mesh shape.

I think topology from below image is probably the cleanest possible. It allows to add **Edge Loops** to control hardness to the edges of indentation or you can use **Mean Crease** there.

I've made indentation by pushing vertices with **Proportional Editing** enabled.

[image]

Comment: the tricky part is how to connect the edge loop from the cylinder to the oval shape outer loop, I usually make them with the same number of vertices then connect them using "Bridge edge loop" but whatever I do, it never end up as a smooth transition.

how did you determine the number of vertices of the oval edge loop? and how do you connect it to the cylinder edge loop?