# Make Surface Subdivision bend the mesh

Tags: mesh, shaders, subdivision-surface

I have a problem, I want to make a simple engine design.

[image: I've got this simple engine design]

But whenever I apply the SubSurf modifier, I run into a problem.Here are some pictures:
[image]
[image]

The corners of the flaps are not positioned well! I found out what the issues is: Surface Subdivision doesn't "bend" the flaps.
(Image where the flaps are a diffrent mesh)
[image]

So my question is: Is there a way (other then manually) to make SubSurf "BEND" the flaps?

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96342/how-to-save-curve-shape-of-cylinder-with-such-deform/96344#96344

Comment: SubSsurf doesn't "bend", like the name says it subdivides. A flat surface will still be flat after subdividing. If you want it bent it must be curved before subdividing

Comment: BTW I am not longer using this engine model(designed a better one), but I would still want to know how to bend it. Oh and @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried subdivideing it a couple of times and manually beding it but no luck.

Comment: I am not quite sure with the phrase "bend". Do you mean you want the segmented edges fit a kind of circle? ... and do you need the slits to be actual meshes?